# Firebase remote config for Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Given that the [firebase_remote_config](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config) Flutter plugin is not support on web, what's the best way to use remote config on web?

Looks like [Dart JS interop](https://pub.dev/packages/js) is one way. Is there a simpler way to handle this?

Comment: it's now supported, but the sdk still throws an error